# Calculate, display and add price based on weight n wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am designing a grocery website in wordpress where in I wish to display price per kg for vegetable and user will now enter the weight they wish and price should get recalculated and displayed and added to cart(after user click on add to cart button).

I have tried few plugins like Price per product and Price Measurement but nothing seems to work. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the price per Kg by the weight requested to get the price.